# Jquery less than or greated issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple time picker using autocomplete. I have an array which has the times I require, every half hour, then the user enters a time in the Start box, say '7.00', which automatically enters the time 1 hour from then into the Finish box, so '8.00'.

This all works fine. 
The problem I'm having is that I would like a way to check that the finish time is not less than or equal to the start time. 
So

```
Start:  7.00   
Finish: 5.00
```

would show an alert.

I created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DB8ZT/3/

on line 173 I thought this would do the check but it just shows the alert everytime I enter a value into the Finish box.

Comment: when you enter value, or pick it from autocomplete dropdown? these are two completely different events

Comment: When I select it from the autocomplete in the Finish box. 
On fsfiddle, enter 7.30 in Start and 4.00 (using the autocomplete) thats when I want the alert box to pop up

Comment: Just thinking, the point you make about just entering the value and not using the autocomplete value. How would I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use `parseFloat()` like this:

```
 var res   = parseFloat(ui.item.value);
 var start = parseFloat($("#start").val());
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/uDKJw/2/

The document is here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Hope this hleps.